# What are some oxygen producing plants for a small room?

Tags: houseplants

I am searching for a list of plants which are easy to maintain, small and would produce enough oxygen for one person in a 25m² room.

Until now I just found two sources:

1. [Plants making oxygen](http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/newton/askasci/1993/biology/bio027.htm)
2. [How to Grow Your Own Fresh Air - TED 2009](http://greenspaces.in/blog/ted09/)

Comment: What do you mean by "enough oxygen for one person"?  Are you planning a trip to space?

Comment: What's the lighting?  No light, no oxygen, I think.  Chlorella is the usual low-maintenance choice for space travel - it's what I use ;-)

Comment: @tim Somewhat related: [Suggestion for houseplants that can clean the air?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1283/394)

Answer (score 5):

I have a great deal of skepticism about the idea that less than an acre of plants in full sun can make a substantial difference in the oxygen levels of an enclosed area.  Most tropical plants that are inside are receiving from 100 to 500 [lux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux).

Outside in the northern hemisphere on a cloudy day is around 50,000 lux.

How can you reduce the amount of light by a factor of 100 and get the same amount of photosynthesis going on? I see a commonly quoted figure of "Plant leaves produce 5 milliliters of oxygen, per leaf, each day." but I don't see under what conditions this is measured under.

I don't think you can produce enough oxygen inside a room unless the roof is glass and you fill it entirely with any type of plant.