# Looking for recommendations for houseplants to freshen up air that do not grow much

Tags: houseplants, plant-recommendations

I do a lot of soldering in my room which smells. Not only that, I find my room smells stale anyway.

Ideally I want a fairly small plant that is easy to maintain and doesn't grow into a forest/ palm tree. It should be widely available too. I live in Manchester in the UK.

Comment: Sansavarias or dracenas would be your natural pick then... Luck bamboo being a small dracena could work if you are an overwaterer most sansavarias would be better for you if you are an underwaterer.

Answer (score 3):

Plants do exchange air but in direct relation the amount of light and water available. [This post goes into detail](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/suggestion-for-houseplants-that-can-clean-the-air?rq=1) about what kind of plants and mentions a ratio of one plant per 100 square feet.  To get an effective filter rate you need good light and adequate water.

From a health and safety point of view [this article](http://employment.alberta.ca/documents/whs/whs-pub_ch032.pdf) has a long list of things you could be breathing when you solder including ozone, carbon monoxides and various metal ions.  You would be safer using a fume hood which exhausts to the outside and buying a plant to deal with the rest.

Comment: Metal ions perhaps... Certainly voc's... Soldering isn't energetic enough for ozone and won't produce CO unless they are using a torch... You are certainly right that the plants should be in an active state of growth.