# Is this the air-cleaning fern?

Tags: identification, ferns

I found numerous suggestions for plants that clean the air in [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/suggestion-for-houseplants-that-can-clean-the-air).

One of the plants mentioned is [the boston fern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephrolepis_exaltata). I have many ferns growing in our backyard, and managed to cultivate a few quite easily. However, I'm not sure that it's the right kind of fern. How can I be sure? Is this, in fact, the boston fern?

[image: my fern]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would appear to be a variety of Nephrolepis, but I'm not sure its actually the Boston fern (Nephrolepis exaltata bostoniensis) - it looks rather more like Nephrolepis cordifolia, though it seems to be a darker green than usual. Either way, both these ferns are listed as good at cleaning up air indoors.