# Flowring Plants that eliminates pollution or aids in cleansing of the room air?

Tags: houseplants

Delhi is very polluted. We are thinking of getting some plants for home. my mother wants beautiful and big flowering(with big flowers) plants. However, I couldn't find any flowering plants that also cleans the air. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Very closely related, but no dupe due to the explicit request for flowers: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/suggestion-for-houseplants-that-can-clean-the-air?rq=1. Find more useful links there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quite extensive list of "air cleaning" plants can be found in the [**NASA Clean Air Study**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Clean_Air_Study).

Taking your desire for (large) flowers into account, you should consider

- [peace lilies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spathiphyllum)
- [flamingo flowers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthurium_andraeanum)
- [gerberas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerbera_jamesonii)
- [florist's daisies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysanthemum_morifolium)
- [dendrobium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrobium) or [moth orchids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalaenopsis)

Now keep in mind that they have different filter properties so you should do some research which pollutants you want to reduce (some green, non-flowering plants may provide stronger "filter power"). The general recommendation is *at least one fully grown plant per 100 square feet*. Healthy plants filter way more than weak and struggling plants. Their cleansing power can drop to nearly zero. So keep them in good health, fulfill their needs with regards to water, light and nutrition and they will pay you back with flowers and somewhat cleaner air.